# Google Slides triggers not available

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to script a Google Slides presentation but the 'from Slides' installable trigger isn't showing up, only timed and calendar.
I've tried using several different accounts, on shared and unshared projects alike. No luck.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Such triggers doesn't exists. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable